# Send byte[] over http

Tags: java, angular, file, http, byte

I do have **get** request over **http** from an angular based *client* side which expects as an answer an array of bytes from a java *server*.

**angular.ts**

```
  downloadDocument(documentId: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('docId', documentId);
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`/downloadpdf/`,
      { params: params});
  }
```

**controller.java**

```
     @GetMapping("/downloadpdf")
        public String downloadDocument(@RequestParam("docId") final String docId) {
            String response = (new String(getBytesArray(docId)));
            // getBytesArray returns a byte[]
            // response correctly computed
            return response;
        }
```

Parsing error is encountered while transmitting over http:
"HttpErrorResponse":

> - **message**: *'Http failure during parsing for http://localhost...'*
> - **error**: *'error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad'*

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I had a google at the error message and it seems that your response is not a valid JSON format. As to why that is the case, I'm not too sure

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you call the overload of `get()` that takes a generic parameter:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(...)
```

This overload sets the response type to JSON, thus telling the HttpClient to parse the response body to JSON and to returned the generated object or array. Since you do not want to receive JSON, you must use another overload.

[The documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) is your friend.

If you want to receive a Blob, for example, you would use the second overload, documented as returning an `Observable<Blob>`, and expecting options with `responseType: 'blob'`.